VS Code server side debugging / breakpoints for Nx / NextJS app?
I have inherited an Nx monorepo using NextJS, Typescript, Yarn (for package), etc. and I cannot get server-side debugging working reliably. Somehow I had it working once, lost it, and honestly I am at my wits end so there must be something stupidly simple that I'm missing. Here's the configuration from my VS Code launch.json:
    {
      "name": "Launch webapp",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nx",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "serve",
        "webapp"
      ],
      "outputCapture": "std",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "env": {
        "NODE_OPTIONS": "--inspect",
        "TS_NODE_IGNORE": "false",
        "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/webapp/tsconfig.json"
      },
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },

(I pieced this together after seeing this StackOverflow question)
Here's what happens when I launch using that:
/home/me/nx-workspace/node_modules/.bin/nx serve webapp
Debugger attached.

> nx run webapp:serve:development
Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
Debugger attached.
Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
   the --inspect option was detected, the Next.js router server should be inspected at port 9230.
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Local:        http://localhost:4300
  - Environments: .env
  - Experiments (use with caution):
    · instrumentationHook
 ✓ Starting...
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
 ○ Compiling /instrumentation ...
 ✓ Compiled /instrumentation in 3.7s (1192 modules)
 ✓ Ready in 7.8s

And breakpoints remain grayed out. I tried attaching to port 9230 in another debugger to no avail. I also get a lot of errors like the following which may be unrelated to this problem:
Debugger attached.
Could not read source map for file:///home/me/nx-workspace/apps/webapp/.next/server/vendor-chunks/next.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/me/nx-workspace/apps/webapp/.next/server/vendor-chunks/script.js.map'
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

I find it odd that the debugger keeps disconnecting and reattaching. Perhaps it has to do with hot-reloading?

Reading the docs from https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging and https://medium.com/@NikolovLazar/debugging-next-js-ec5a6c889f7b
I think that you need to configure "cwd" also:
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/webapp"

Finally, here is a similar case: Debug Next.js App with VSCode in NX monorepo
There you will see some differences on runtimeExecutable, the solition on that thread is usign yarn instead nx
"runtimeExecutable": "yarn",

Hope it solve your problem!

That SO link is the same one I referenced in my question. Changing the working directory won't work because then you can't launch nx or yarn (it won't find the package.json)
